# Can vim recognize when it is used in Console2?

Tags: vim, console2

With [Steven Harman's Solarized tweak](https://github.com/stevenharman/console2-solarized) for Console2 I can more or less use the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme in win32 vim.  But once in a while I find myself in vim via a vanilla cmd.exe window and the Solarized 16-color colorscheme is not aligned to it gui equivalent.

So I'd like to fix this inside my vimrc, but how can I check if console vim is being used in Console2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Console2, you can set arbitrary environment variables by modifying the *shell* invocation (from the Settings dialog, or directly in the XML config). For the default Windows command prompt, use a value of:

```
cmd.exe /K set EMULATOR=console2
```

For Cygwin Bash, something like this should work:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "export EMULATOR=console2; exec /bin/bash -i"
```

Then, check for the `$EMULATOR` value in a conditional in your `.vimrc`, as outlined by romainl's answer.

Answer (score 0):

See if your terminal emulator sets an environment variable or if you can set one in one way or another.

In `bash`, one would do:

```
$ export EMULATOR=console2
```

With that out of the way, you can put something like this in your `_vimrc`:

```
if $EMULATOR == "console2"
  colorscheme foo
else
  colorscheme bar
endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately Console2 doesn't appear to set any environment variables and I don't know how to make it do so. I'm interested as well if anyone can figure out how to detect it...